# Expected value given density $(E(g(x))$, stuck on integration, law of unconscious statistician)

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

so I need to show that:
$$
E(X^n) = n\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}P(X>x) \, dx
$$
where $X$ has density $f$, and $f(x)=0$ for all $x<0$, $n>0$.
Here's what I did so far:
$$
E(X^n) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^nf(x) \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} x^n f(x) \, dx
$$
Now I've tried using integration by parts by letting $u = x^n, du=nx^{n-1}\,dx; dv=f(x)\,dx, v=F(x)$, so the integral becomes:
$$
x^nF(x)|_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1}F(x)\,dx=
x^nF(x)|_0^{\infty} -\int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1}P(X \le x)\,dx=\\
x^nF(x)|_0^{\infty} -\int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1}P(X \le x)\,dx=
x^nF(x)|_0^{\infty} -\int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1}(1-P(X>x))\,dx
$$
I think I'm really close, but just don't know where to go from here. Any ideas?

So sorry about that, I copied down the question wrong and never realized it. I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: 1) You cannot divide the integral of $1-P(X>x)$ into two summands since $\int_{-\infty}^0nx^{n-1}dx$ diverges. 2)What do you eventually want to prove? I told you that your original statement is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Ahhhhh my apologies, I'm so sorry guys, I've been staring at this for a while and realized that I made a mistake, editing the question again: **$f(x)=0, \forall{x}<0, n>0$**

Comment: See my edited post then.

Comment: Thank you @drhab, @Vossler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE** The original portion of the answer refers to the previous edit of the question that concerned the non-positive RVs instead of nonnegative ones.

This cannot be true: since $P(X>x)=0 \,\forall{x}>0$, your right - hand side is always zero.

Actually, you have arrived at a correct expression in the end.

**EDIT** For your corrected problem formulation,

$$
EX^n=\int_0^\infty x^nf(x)dx = -\int_0^\infty x^n(P(X>x))^\prime_xdx=-x^nP(X>x)|_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty nx^{n-1}P(X>x)dx=\int_0^\infty nx^{n-1}P(X>x)dx.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative route:

$$n\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}P\left(X>x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}1_{\left(x,\infty\right)}\left(y\right)dF\left(y\right)dx$$

Now switch the order of integration to arrive at:
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}1_{\left(x,\infty\right)}\left(y\right)dxdF\left(y\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}nx^{n-1}dxdF\left(y\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{n}dF\left(y\right)=\mathbb EX^n$$

Comment: It is explicitly said that $X$ is non-positive.

Comment: @Vossler I repaired up to a certain level.

Comment: Removed my downvote then. However, I think that the OP has already done the job himself because his last expression is pretty much the best you can get (spotting that $x^nF(x)|_{-\infty}^0=0$ and $1-P(X>x)=F(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to let this sink in, @Vossler how is $x^n F(x)|_{-\infty}^0 = 0$?

Comment: @UNOwen $x^nF(x)|_{-\infty}^0=(x^nF(x))|_{x=0}-\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^nF(x)$. First summand is zero; for the second, if the expectation exists (which is what has to be assumed if we want to speak about it at all), the limit should exist and be $0$ by the necessary condition of improper integral convergence.

Comment: So could we continue as follows, going to edit my question...

Comment: This answer shows that the statement is true for *any* nonnegative random variable. It is not necessary that the distribution has a PDF.

Comment: I wish I could mark both as answers - I upvoted both though. Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for the upvote.